# One development machine with multiple versions of SSDT for BI development

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

With the announcement of VS2013 i need to be able to have the following:

-Main Development IDE: Visual Studio 2013

-Integration Services with SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2008/R2.

-Integration Services with SQL Server 2012.

Unfortunately i cant upgrade all my SQL Servers to the latest release so i have to maintain a diversified dev env in my laptop.

What i need to do in order to have all the above in one machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this is the answer :(

[Interoperability and Coexistence (Integration Services)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522577.aspx)

Also a post made yesterday specifically for SQL Server 2012/2014

[SQL Server Data Tools – Business Intelligence downloads](http://www.mattmasson.com/2013/10/sql-server-data-tools-business-intelligence-downloads/)

Separate install for each SSIS version i need to develop for.

So it may be like:

1. Full Visual Studio 2013 for all development except SSIS
2. VS2012 Shell for SSIS SQL Server 2012
3. VS2008 Shell for SSIS SQL Server 2008 and 2008/R2